# Number of ways in which exactly $1$ person is alive

Tags: combinatorics

The following question was given by my teacher in an assignment.

> There is a group of $6$ persons. The $6$ persons shoot each other, no one shoots himself. Everyone shoots exactly once and no shot is wasted. Number of ways in which at the end, there is exactly $1$ person alive is $K$. What is the value of $K$?

#### My approach

I'm thinking that it is similar to number of functions from $\mathrm{A ⟶ A}$
such that $n(A)=6$ ; $n(B)=5$ and $f(i) \neq i$ , $\mathrm{A}$={1,2,3,4,5,6}

Let $E_6$ be the total number of ways

Let $1$ is missing from range has  $6$ choices

Let $f(1)=2$ has  $5$ choices. This has 2 possibilities

1. Any one of $f(3)$, $f(4)$, $f(5)$ and $f(6)$ is also equal to 2.
   Effectively $f(i) \neq i$  which can occur in $D_5$ ways.
2. None of $f(2)$, $f(3)$, $f(4)$and $f(6)$ is equal to 2. It can be done in $\frac{1}{5}E_5$ ways.

So, $E_6 = 6*5*D_5 + 6*5*4*D_4 + ....$ and so on.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: It's hard to say where you went wrong because "and proceeded further" is probably where the error is.

Comment: @JohnDouma I've added that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us generalize the problem and let $f(n)$ be the number for a group of $n$ people; the problem asks for $f(6)$.

With $n$ people, suppose person $p_i$ is the only surviver.
If we remove $p_i$ from the game, two things can happen:

- Among the remaining $n-1$ people, there is exactly one survivor, which must be the one $p_i$ shot. In this case, we arrive at $n\cdot f(n-1)$ possibilities: $n$ for the choice of $p_i$ and $f(n-1)$ for the result within the smaller group - the target of $p_i$ is determined by the latter
- The remaining $n-1$ people kill each other. This means thet the map shooter $\mapsto$ shotee is a fixpoint-free permutation (aka. derangement) and the target of $p_i$ is (redundantly) any of these people.  This makes $n\cdot (n-1)\cdot {!(n-1)}$

In summary,

$$ f(n)=n\cdot f(n-1)+n\cdot(n-1)\cdot {!(n-1)}$$

We lookup the [number of derangements](https://oeis.org/A000166) $$
!1=0, !2=1, !3=2, !4=9, !5=44, \ldots
$$ and use this to unwrap this recursion:

We can let this recursion unfold from the starting point $f(2)=0$, i.e.,
$$f(3)=3f(2)+3\cdot 2\cdot {!2}= 6$$
$$f(4)=4f(3)+4\cdot 3\cdot {!3}= 48$$
$$f(5)=5f(4)+5\cdot 4\cdot {!4}= 420$$
$$f(6)=6f(5)+6\cdot 5\cdot {!5}= 3840$$

---

It turns out that this sequence is already in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A037184)